# Apple Store previews and screenshots

Tags: ios, image, screen, screenshot, screen-resolution

We developed ios app. Now we are creating Prepare for Submission
Save section. Apple want to screenshot for us. But we have no require devices. Actually we are using webview. And we have a android app in play store. Just ı opened inspect mode on crome and take a screenshots and upload play store app information. I want to do same thing in appstore but I cant. How can ı solve this problem.
Actually ı tried image resize on photoshop but image quality is very bad if take screenshot on windows
They want 6.5 inch (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR)

1242 x 2688 pixels (portrait)

2688 x 1242 pixels (landscape)

Comment: You can use ios simulator to take screenshots!

Comment: I cant access my mac now

Comment: @meteeroğlu well you will need your mac.. how do you expect someone here to help you with this problem?

Comment: Webview only apps will be rejected by apple

Comment: No we published

Comment: I solved my problem. I open chrome inspect mode and take screenshot in inspect mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots should be in the right dimensions. [Here](https://docs.appmanager.io/docs/screenshot-sizes) you can check what they are.

And it is important the screenshots that you have to be for the right phone. 
What I mean is that some screenshots can be as marketing screenshots. Imagine some additional info on the image and just part of the phone shown in there. But you need to display the right device there. You can check [Colibra](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/colibra/id1460357411?ls=1) app in App Store.

Maybe this example can give you a good idea of how to generate your screenshots.

Comment: is it important to add app previews to accept my app?

Comment: what do you mean with app previews?

Comment: You need to present your functionality if the screenshots or the app preview are not enough or they are not clear they can reject you. If you think about the video content only, it is not mandatory to have it in order to accept your app.